# pass arguments to junit from command prompt through ant

Tags: junit

I am executing a `Junit` test case that takes user inputs.

`Junit` is executed through `ANT`, but the script abruptly exits stating

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

is it possible to pass dynamic input this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Java System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for this. But I think that your unit test should not be dependent of any user input. It should executes all the time the same to ensure your code is working.